# What is the difference in pronunciation of "quand" and "con"?

Tags: prononciation, voyelles, nasalisation

I know that there is a liaison between the final "d" in "quand" and a following vowel, but is there a difference for each word in isolation?

Comment: Just look at https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/quand#French and check the "pronunciation" section.

Comment: Did you take the time out of your day to downvote a question from a year and a half ago only to provide an unproductive comment? Really?

Comment: Throsby, meaning no offence, did you take the time time of your day to ask a question which is googlable in a minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These words don't mean the same thing at all. In pronunciation, quand [kɑ̃] et con [kɔ̃]

Some examples :

- J'ai 20 ans = I am 20. ("Ans" has the same pronunciation of **an** in quand)
- Il faut qu'on aille chez Pierre = We need to go at Pierre's home. ("qu'on" has the same pronunciation as **con**)

But please, don't use "con", I don't think you will have to in a translation. It is a vulgar word.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *quand* and *con* (also *qu'on*) are pronounced with distincts (at least for native ears) nasalisations, \ɑ̃\ for the former and \ɔ̃\ for the latter.

Ref: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_French)

Answer (score 2):

The "an" in "quand" is nasal and open.
The "on" in "con" is more palatal and close.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the pronouciation is not that different, but if you have a good level in french you will distinguish between the two just from the context, for example: "C'est quand on va y aller à la piscine?" and " Mais t'es con !"

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a phonetic dictionnary to hear the differences, it's important to be able to make the difference.
http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/on/553284
(number 4, qu'on)
and 
http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/quand/64737